# Android data collecting form

Tags: android, forms

Basically my android project is around making a form to be filled up by the user of the app. And send this data to the php server. The data may be collected offline so the app should also save the datas unless its in the reach of wifi or gprs network. I'm early beginner to android and got stuck in between. Can any one suggest me a similar project sample so tat I could make a study and learn the stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like a good use case for a hybrid client-server app.  Use the mobile device to collect forms and store their results in a SQLite database.  Whenever an appropriate wireless network is available, connect up with the server-based app and upload all the data.  There are many good ways to do this, but for starters, consider making the server app implement a RESTful API and have the mobile device use this API to send in the data.  If messing around with a server sounds like fun, I've had good luck with MySQL + CakePHP.  One of the cool aspects of CakePHP is it gives you RESTful access to your database almost for free.  Or, you can use something like Google App Engine and let someone else worry about administering the server.

Comment: Thank you sparky for the answer. Here with your answer i'm lil confused with the restful apis? how can dynamically upload the datas taken through the mobile to my mysql database